# 'Files not found' error when using Webpack in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webpack

I'm trying to build an app using Webpack and Cordova.
I put the contents of my webpack 'dist' folder into my cordova 'www' folder and then I build it for Android and emulate it.

When the app opens I get a lot of 'ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND' erros, when I open my compiled index.html I see that there is a '/' in front of every link that causes the error because it points to the wrong directory.

> **Example**
> *'src=/static/js/example.js'*

If I remove the first '/' manually and rebuild the app for Android it works.

How do I remove those '/' when I compile my project so I don't have to manually edit every link after compiling?

> **Example:**
>
> It should look for the files in the same folder as the index.html: *"file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/"*
>
> instead it goes to:
> *'file:///static/js/example.js'*

(The static map is in the same directory as the index.html)

**Note:** When I open the index.html directly in the browser the links work

Comment: Adding  `publicPath: ''` to the webpack config seemed to have resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding  `publicPath: ''` to the webpack config seemed to have resolved the issue!